# How to train factorization machines

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I've been interested in factorization machines for a while now, trying to get along with second order before going any higher.
After reading Rendle's original article (2010), I switched to this one : https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.08810.pdf since the author gives more informations about high order factorization machines (at least for m=3).

I'm trying to implement the pseudocode he gave but I'm having some doubts :
1/ Section 7, he introduces the loss fuction $\textit{l}$, says it's $\mu$-smooth. What does that mean ? And more important, from where does the $\mu$ come from ? For $\beta$ for example, he said specifically that he obtained it by cross-validation but he said absolutely nothing about $\mu$.

2/ As given in this article, $$\hat{y}_{FM}(x,w,P)=<w,x>+\hat{y}_{A^2}(x,1,P)$$
The algorithm he gives provides training for $\hat{y}_{A^2}(x,1,P)$ and thus for $P$. For $w$, the article says :
"$w \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is a vector of first-order weights, estimated from training data".
Does this mean we have to go through a separated learning to get $w$ ? Why wouldn't we include it in the same algorithm running for $P$ ?

3/ At last, in the pseudo-code he gave, how can we interpret $\delta$ as an error ? I'm more used to the error (at least during the learning bit) defined as a difference between two objects and here there's this division.

Thank you all !

**EDIT 1 :** So I found an answer for my last question. $\delta$ is in fact $f'(\theta)/f"(\theta)$, given that we want to minimize $f$ w.r.t $\theta$.

**EDIT 2 :** Also found the answer to my first question. The squared loss is 1-smooth, that's why the author didn't mention $\mu$ anymore when he chose squared loss as the loss function to work with.

My second question remains unanswered though and it's giving me headach !

Answer (score -1):

2/ you can say w is part of FM parameters. normal FM have first-order、second-order and higher-order parameters

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our standards. Can you expand
on it? We can also turn it into a comment.